# readonly attribute needs to be permission based

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webform that has an input field that gets changed to read only which is fine. I would like to make it permission based so that if an admin logs in, they can alter this field if it is required.

```
<input name="_ctl0:MainContent:txtNameAs" type="text" value="Some Company Name" readonly="readonly" id="_ctl0_MainContent_txtNameAs" tabindex="1" class="bgColor1" style="border-width:0px;width:280px;" />
```

I'm sure this can be handled with a little JS but my knowledge of Java Script is nil. Any advice or direction would be wonderful.

Comment: You need to use server side code to control it. It is very easy to defeat client side security.

Answer (score 0):

try this : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tp5g4vfb/)

```
$("#readonly").on("click",function(){
    $("#input").attr("readonly",true);
});
$("#writable").on("click",function(){
    $("#input").attr("readonly",false);
});
```

or something like:

```
var USER_HAS_PERMISSION = true;
$("#input").attr("readonly",USER_HAS_PERMISSION);
```

**DO NOT use client-side security control!**

Comment: this solution works, but does not explain the pitfalls of such an approach. namely, the fact that this kind of client-side security is _trivially_ defeated. also, it would be nice if you explained what your code actually does some more.

Comment: indeed, do not use client-side security control.